# How do I get the Router navigate extra "replaceUrl" to work correctly?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a contact addition form that can be navigated to from multiple screens in our application.

Once the form is submitted, I then take the user to a screen to view the contact that was added.

When the user then makes use of the back button it should take them back to the screen that they originated from.

This might be the Android back button or one that calls the `RouterExtensions` back function.

I have made use of the navigate extra `replaceUrl` when navigating away from the form to the view page.

I have also tried using the `skipLocationChange` extra when navigating to the form but this creates more issues.

I have created a simple playground page flow that creates not quite the same issue but does throw an error that I don't know what to do with either:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=BfVcGZ&v=2

In our app, by making use of the `replaceUrl` extra, the back button does take the user to the correct page.

However, there is a brief moment where they see the form again. This isn't an ideal user experience.

In the linked Playground I do get an error:

> Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route.

This seems to tell me that `replaceUrl` is indeed removing the page from the route table.

However, the page isn't destroyed yet and so the app is trying to show a page that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceUrl` is not yet supported by Page Router Outlet, there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/705), you might want to register your vote on the feature and follow up there for further updates.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I looked and searched through that list of tickets and missed it somehow.